# Gtk how to calculate width of the string in pixels

Tags: c, gtk

Gtk how should I calculate width of the string in pixels.
I have created a markup string using `g_markup_printf_escaped` and I want to calculate width of the string in pixels not in chars.

Does `Pango` provides any function to calculate string length in pixels, depending on font type, size and weight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get PangoLayout size using pango_layout_get_pixel_size () function:

http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/pango/pango-Layout-Objects.html#pango-layout-get-pixel-size

Comment: just written this function which returns width in pixels:void GetTextWidthInPixel( GtkWidget *label, char *Font_family, double point_size, int weight, bool font_style, char *stringtomeasure,int *width, int *height );